# beamer installation and complinig problem

Tags: beamer

I am trying to install beamer in a new system acer 64 bit, window 10. I have downloaded basic miktex 2.9 and installed . I am using win edit 10.3. The tex document works fine. But when I compile any beamer fime, first error came "translator.sty" not found. So I opened miktex console and add it. Recompiling it gave error, "times.sty"  not found. So agin i add from the package. But at this point , The Same error coming  and I am not able to obtain the ppt in pdf.

Let me know the solution

Comment: times.sty is in the psnfss package. But you probably would have less trouble if you simply install everything.